# If $f: (0,1)\to \mathbf R$ is a homeo, how can the preimage of $\mathbf R$ be open?

Tags: general-topology

If $f: (0,1)\to\mathbf R$ is a homeomorphism, the preimage of $\mathbf R$ (which is closed) must also be closed. How does that work?

Comment: The preimage must be closed *in $(0, 1)$*, which is different to being closed in $\Bbb R$. Indeed, $(0, 1)$ is closed in $(0, 1)$ so there are no problems.

Comment: The preimage is $(0,1)$, which is both open and closed in $(0,1)$.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Gotcha.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually true for any function whose domain is a topological space. The domain is the given set on which the function is defined, at its every point.

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a function from a topological space $X$, which is the domain of $f$, to any set $Y$. Then, the pre-image of $f$ is  just $X$ by definition. In other words, $f^{-1}(Y)=X$.

But, $X$ is both open and closed in its topology. So, the pre-image of $f$ is a closed set.

Your question is just a special case: $X=(0,1)$, $Y=\Bbb{R}$ and $f$ is homeomorphism.

Recall:

A homeomorphism is a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ from a "topological space" $X$ to another "topological sapace" $Y$ such that:

i) $f$ is continuous.

ii) $f$ is $1-1$.

iii) $f$ is onto.

iv) $f^{-1}$ exists and it is continuous.

So, the only property of homeomorphism used here is that the domain $X$ is a topological space.